# how to make chosen select go over parent div

Tags: css, jquery-chosen

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/2/) which shows the `chosen-select` control being 'truncated' by it's parent `div`. And even though the `overflow` is set to hidden for the y-axis, it's showing the scroll bar anyway when clicking on the `chosen-select` control.

The `height` of this parent `div` is fixed and set to `200px`, and needs to remain this way.

How can I make `chosen-select` go over the parent `div` when clicked upon?

**EDIT:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/6/) updated with more `CSS`.
If I **comment** the `div.content`, it doesn't mess up the layout.

The `chosen-select` control is now on top of the 4th header. In this fiddle I can still select the `chosen-select` control, but in my application I can't.

Is there something I need to do for the header's positions?

**EDIT2:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/9/). I just noticed that the `chosen-select` control stays on its place when heading 1/2 are sliding up. For the record, this doesn't happen in my application.

What does happen, is when you slide up the 3rd `heading`, `chosen-select` control is visible until it's slided up all the way. Unlike the other heading's, where the `input`'s  are slowly hiding.

Comment: So you want `chosen-select` to actually cascade outside of your `fixed` div with a height of 200?

Comment: Yes, the actual height is larger, but this `chosen-select` control is placed at the bottom. The jsFiddle is just reassembling the problem i'm having with it's restriction.

Comment: Updated answer... again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Simply add this CSS class:

**Added border to show you the definition of your other box is staying `fixed`.**

`div.content {
    position:absolute;
}`

[image]

#### View Here: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/e62Wu/3/

When you select position:absolute, you are effectively telling it to ignore the constraints of your fixed parent div and be able to bound outside the box.

**Does this answer the question? I can elaborate further if you'd like.**

#### EDIT:

`absolute positioning` will remove it from the flow of the rest of the document and treat it as if it didn't exist (it displays where you tell it to, but will not modify other element flow).

Try just adding a spacer like so:

**CSS:**

```
div.filler {
    height:30px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
...
<div class="filler">
<div class="content">
     <select class="chosen-select">
     ...
```

#### FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/7/

#### ANOTHER Edit:

#### Try this:

### JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/e62Wu/10/

**Add CSS:**

```
.hider {
    position:static;
}
```

**Add ID in HTML:**

```
<div id="dropper" class="heading">header 3 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></div>
```

**Add jQuery if/else:**

```
    if($this.attr('id')==='dropper'){
       $('.content').toggleClass('hider').toggleClass('content');
    }
```

Comment: Your approach seems to work in the jsFiddle. However, I can't get it to work in my application. Is there something you might know that blocks this from working? I'm inspecting the elements, but I don't see `div.content { position:absolute; }` any where in the CSS block.

Comment: Show me a fiddle with your full CSS.

Comment: You didn't close the filler div. Is it meant to wrap the `content` div?

Comment: lolz @ me. Yes it is: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/8/). We are just establishing a block element that will **fake** the height of your button.

Comment: It seems to work, but I have chevron's on those `heading`'s. When clicked, the headers will slide up or down. But that `chosen-select` control stays in sight and when it's totally closed, it's hidden. See my new fiddle, question updated.

Comment: Updated for you. Please mark this answer if accepted, and proceed to ask further questions on a new post. We don't want to bury relevant information others may want to use deep within irrelevant posts :-). Happy to help.

Comment: Ironically, I was about to do just what you suggested, but I'm back at square one. After toggling the header 3 (close then open), the `chosen-select` control is not cascading outside it's parent `div`...

Comment: That doesn't mean this doesn't answer your question and provide a working fiddle for future coders to reference...

Comment: Is there any way to do it without the `absolute` positioning? I have a footer underneath the div and my dropdown keeps going below the footer :/

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

to the parentbox, and removed "overflow: hidden" and the dropdown stays in front of the div.

It was not based on any prior knowledge, just dumb luck. I was trying to figure out the exact borders of the divs...oh well.

It's always something...

Comment: Tried what you did with removing the `overflow:hidden`, but didn't do the trick. Anything else you might have changed that you forgot to mention?

Comment: Here's the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/e62Wu/4/. I had to change the childbox also.