# chosen select in a table with horizontal scroll

Tags: css, jquery-chosen

I have a table with multiple columns. This table suppose to have a horizontal scroll in my application. It is also suppose to have a chosen-select control in one of it's cells.

I had a problem with the chosen select dropdown (being cut) by it's parent div but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271804/how-to-make-chosen-select-go-over-parent-div) solution which solved a similar issue by wrapping the chosen-select with a `div` and giving it `position: absolute`

But this solution is creating another issue for me as the absolute position is removing the cell from the flow of the rest of the table's cells.

[Take a look here and try to scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/ziadvictor/rj7rsyp5/4/)

Any idea?